# How to add an id to an array by clicking on checkbox with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, thymeleaf

I have a table with some values, the last input is a checkbox.
I need to save the id of the input into an array only when is checked.

This is my partial table:

```
<table id="produtcTable" class="table">
   <thead class="thead-dark">
       <tr>
           <th scope="col">Producto</th>
           <th scope="col">Precio de lista</th>
           <th scope="col">Agregar</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr th:each="stock : ${stockList}">
           <td th:text="${stock.productName}"></td>
           <td th:text="${stock.price}"></td>
           <td class="text-center">
               <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" th:attr="id=${stock.stockCode}" onclick="myFunction(this)" aria-label="...">
```

this is my javascript that does not work:

```
<script >
   function myFunction(product) {
       var arr= [];
       $('input[id='+ product.id +']:checked').each(function () {
             arr.push(product.id);
             });
        alert(arr.toString());
        };
</script>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: i think for the `onclick` to work you need to put it in a wrapper around the input

Comment: Have you tried console.log(product) ?  Or console.log($('input[id='+ product.id +']:checked')) ?  I suspect you'll find some of your issues there...

Comment: I'm going to try it

Comment: @devlincarnate i confirm that the id is shown, but i can't see the array in the alert

Comment: have you tried iterating over the array to see its contents?  (or use console.log() so you can inspect it).

Comment: Let's try! I'm new on this, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a id attribute on you checkbox in you snippets. But there is some code i can not identify (not mentioned in post) setting the id. Please make sure there is an id in your current DOM (Browser Development tools: inspector). According to your snippet you can try the follwing:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" onclick="myFunction(this)"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb2" onclick="myFunction(this)"/>
```

and the following JS code would update an global array the the clicked checkbox id:

```
var arr= [];
function myFunction(inputCB) {
  arr.push(inputCB.id);
  alert(arr);
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! that was fast. Thank you!